# The GridView 'grid' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-index-changed

```
public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString =
            WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["base"].ConnectionString;
            string selectSQL = "SELECT author,book FROM ListItem";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "ListItem");
            grid.DataSource = ds;
            grid.DataBind();  
        }
        protected void grid_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            grid.PageIndex=e.NewPageIndex;//have a error    grid.DataBind();                                      

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You have handled the wrong event, change it to `PageIndexChanging`. (and you need to hook it up in the aspx code)

```
protected void grid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
   grid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
   grid.DataBind();
}
```

And you need to surround the binding of the grid in the page load with a `if(!Page.IsPostback){//do binding }`

Comment: Don't forget to add it to the aspx page: `<asp:GridView OnPageIndexChanging="grid_PageIndexChanging" .... `